# Basic iptables NAT port forwarding

Tags: iptables, nat, port-forwarding

I have three machines: A local PC (public IP 1.2.3.4), an Ubuntu 10 Server box in a datacentre (eth0 on 5.6.7.8 public IP), and a third-party server hosting a website outside of my network (let's say Slashdot on 216.34.181.45).

- Using iptables, how do I access Slashdot from my local machine using 5.6.7.8:8080 ?
- Would this process differ if Slashdot was on the same LAN as my Ubuntu box?
- Can this be done with just NAT PREROUTING/POSTROUTING, or do I need MASQUERADE?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

```
   PC ----- Ubuntu 10 Server ----- Slashdot 
(1.2.3.4)      (5.6.7.8)        (216.34.181.45)
```

1. Enable the IP forwarding on Ubuntu:

   ```
   echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
   ```

   and add the following rules:

   ```
   iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -p tcp -m tcp --dport 8080 -j DNAT \
                                          --to-destination 216.34.181.45:80 
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 5.6.7.8
   ```
2. No.
3. You should use MASQUERADE if the Ubuntu has a dynamic IP:

   ```
   iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
   ```

---

You can also use SSH local port forwarding in this case by executing the below command on the Ubuntu:

```
$ ssh -L 5.6.7.8:8080:216.34.181.45:80 -N user@216.34.181.45
```

---

There's still another (or more) way to do this. Take a look at the [rinetd](http://www.boutell.com/rinetd/):

```
Name       : rinetd
Arch       : i386
Version    : 0.62
Release    : 6.el5.art
Size       : 41 k
Repo       : installed
Summary    : TCP redirection server
URL        : http://www.boutell.com/rinetd
License    : GPL
Description: rinetd is a daemon which redirects TCP connections from one IP address
           : and port to another IP address and port. This daemon is often used to
           : access services behind a firewall.
```

The configuration is very simple. Add the belows line into `/etc/rinetd.conf`:

```
5.6.7.8 8080 216.34.181.45 80
```

and start:

```
# /etc/init.d/rinetd start
Starting rinetd:                                           [  OK  ]
```

It will do everything for you.

Comment: Fantastic. The iptables version works like a charm. I was missing the POSTROUTING rule, and was getting nowhere.


If anyone's trying to do this with a saved .conf file, this is what you're after:


`*nat
-A PREROUTING -p tcp -m tcp -i eth0 --dport 8080 -j DNAT --to-destination 216.34.181.45:80
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -j SNAT --to-source 5.6.7.8
COMMIT`

Comment: Follow-up question here: http://serverfault.com/questions/326837/iptables-nat-port-fowarding-and-apache-log-ips

Comment: Perfect! Just a quick question. When the response packet comes back to the ubuntu server with a destination address of 5.6.7.8, what is the module responsible for modifying the packet and returning it back to 1.2.3.4? Is it the "connection tracking" module?