# How can I access a local-area LDAP through a VPN?

Tags: ssh, vpn, ldap, ssh-tunnel

I need access to an LDAP server hosted on a private network from the outside. I have been given a VPN account but that account has no direct access to the LDAP server. (for security reasons, they refuse to open the LDAP server on VPN).

But I have access to several other *nix boxes, all with root acces and those boxes can acces the LDAP server. My question is, can I use those boxes with something like ssh port forwarding to make the LDAP available?

Comment: Do you have ssh account on the LDAP server?

Comment: No, I don't and I doubt they will create me one.

Comment: http://serverfault.com/a/326577/59925

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution so far thanks to **quanta**.

I installed rinetd on the bound server with the following rule :

```
0.0.0.0 389 myldapserver 389
```

That way, I can directly define my LDAP host as the boundserver on port 389.